# Find HTML table rows containing input value

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-table

Idea is to build-up a filter which would return HTML rows containing filter input value.

I came up with this so far but it returns nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cgi
import re
import urllib

data = cgi.FieldStorage()
filter = data.getvalue('request')

tree = urllib.urlopen('myfile.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(tree)
tables = soup.findChildren('table')

mytable = tables[0]

rows = mytable.findAll('tr')
userrows = [t for t in rows if t.findAll(text=filter)]

text_file = open("tst.txt", "aw")
text_file.write(userrows)
text_file.close()
```

Tried with `userrows = mytable.find('tr', text=filter)` but same outcome. Cmd says "expected a character buffer object"

What could be a possible issue here?

PC. I tried converting `text=str(filter)` but same outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there a five kind of filter that beautifulsoup sport:

1. A string
2. A regular expression
3. A list
4. True
5. A function

make sure your filter is one of those.